# How to show verticla scroll bar in mobile based browser

Tags: mobile-website

I have written following code and i m testing on my smartphone but i m not getting inside scroll bar. Which i am seeing perfect on pc browser.

```
<body>
    <blockquote style="text-align: left; width: 150px; height: 50px; overflow-y: scroll">
        <a href="index.php">HOME</a><br />
        <a href="aboutus.php">ABOUT US </a><br />
        <a href="index.php">HOME</a><br />
        <a href="aboutus.php">ABOUT US </a>
    </blockquote>
</body>
```

I am seeing everythig is showing consecutive without vertical scroll bar,

Comment: Its not issue with smartphone this is not seeing in any mobile.What the else happening ?

Comment: Have you tried just setting the page width to being larger than the browser width? That seems to be the simplest option

Comment: @JamesGoodwin he's asking for the vertical scrollbar, not horizontal. It's also happening to me, is there any solution?

Comment: Yeah, I'm have the same problem like this topic described. Have anybody give some point to solve this problem. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

http://barrow.io/overflow-scrolling

> With the exception of Safari and Opera Mobile, there are no scroll
>   indicators.

You can test this for yourself here:
http://barrow.io/lab/overflow/

This has been noted to work on both android and ios stock browsers:

http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

It's also been noted to stop working on later versions ios.

*-pike